# windows 7 c++ pointer address

Tags: c++, windows-10, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7-x64

I work on an application that runs Windows OSes. Right now, it's running on Windows 7 32-bit and 64-bit, and Windows 2008 R2 64-bit. The application is a .NET app that is compiled for both x86 and x64.

Anyway, this application uses third party COM objects. There are 32-bit and 64-bit versions of these COM objects. These COM objects are written in C++/ATL.

Recently, we have discovered a problem with the 64-bit COM Objects. From talking to the developer of these COM objects, the code is casting pointers (64-bit) to longs (32-bit) and then back to pointers. Of course, this is bad as the cast to longs could truncate the pointer value.

What's strange is these COM objects have been working fine on Windows 7 64-bit and Windows Server 2008 R2 74-bit for a year or so. Never had a problem.

Now when we test on Windows 10 we are getting crashes in these COM objects.

The reason is for this is obvious. What I don't understand is why does this only happen in Windows 10. The developer who wrote the COM objects is only seeing the pointers taking up the lower 32-bits. The upper 32-bits are always zero. On Windows 10, the pointers are using addresses larger than just the 32-bits--i.e. the upper 32-bits are NOT all zeros.

Has anyone heard of this? Is this intentional by MS?

Thanks!

Comment: Windows 10 has as address layout randomisation on by default.  Windows 7 does not have this functionality.  This is a anti hacking measure to ensure modules get loaded at unpredictable addresses.  See also: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20161014-00/?p=94515

Comment: @Richard: I may be mistaken, but I don't think the difference is whether ASLR is on by default, but whether or not it uses addresses above 4GB by default.  Either way, though, it explains the OPs observations.

Comment: I've never heard of that issue, but a quick fix _might_ be using MSVC extension [`__ptr32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985900.aspx), to declare 32-bit pointers on 64-bit Windows.  (Note that the official documentation is a bit misleading, according to [this blog](http://blog.aaronballman.com/2013/05/msvc-pointer-type-attributes/).)  I say "might" because I have no idea whether Windows 10 will play nicely with them, or how to tell it that you need at least some of your memory to be in the range addressable by a 32-bit pointer.

Comment: This might help, or it might make things worse.  I honestly don't know.  It's just the only thing that comes to mind that might let you work around the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the insight on ASLR. Found the below link on Raymond Chen's blog.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20161014-00/?p=94515

Comment: "Found the below link on Raymond Chen's blog" doesn't really make sense. What I meant was, see the Raymond Chen's blog about it. Below is the link.

Comment: blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20161014-00/?p=9451